# Can the set $f(A)$ still be referred to as the *image of the set $A$ under $f$* if $f$ is a relation but not a function?

Tags: terminology, inverse-function

The existence of the inverse image of a set $A$ under $f$, written as $f^{-1}(A)$, does not indicate that $f^{-1}$, the inverse of $f$, exists or that $f$ has any inverse function. In the other direction, can the set $f(A)$ still be referred to as the *image of the set $A$ under $f$* if $f$ is a relation but not a function?

Comment: Yes, this generalization works.

Comment: Note that what you call $f(A)$ is the same as $A\circ f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any binary relation have a domain and a range, so yes, you can define the range of a binary relation like this, for any chosen set $A$. In mathematical notation, suppose that $R\subset X\times Y$, then for some set $H$ we can set

$$R(H):=\{u\in Y:(\exists s\in H:sRu)\}$$

Then $R(H)$ is the "image" of $H$ in the range of $R$.

Comment: I have a question to clarify this. Does the part "$: sRu$" mean "such that there exists a collection of ordered pairs containing one element $s$ (which is an element of $H$) and one element $u$ (which is any element of $Y$)"? In other words, is saying that $H$ is related to $Y$ the same as saying that such a collection of ordered pairs (a relation) exists? (I'm assuming that specifying which $s$ and $u$, as elements of their respective sets, are included in the ordered pairs which are the relation depends on the properties of $R$, the relation, which are here left unspecified.)

Comment: I'm afraid I might have misunderstood.

Comment: $sRu$ means that $(s,r) \in R$. It is the standard notation for binary relations. $H$ is not necessarily related to $Y$ or to $X$.